# Can't add local texmf directory in latest Miktex

Tags: miktex, texmf, console

I installed the portable version (from Scoop) of MikTeX 2.9.6615-x64 on Windows 10 (as I did before with previous Miktex versions).

When I try to add a custom texmf directory for local packages in the MikTeX Console, it shows among the default paths (just above the default Install directory, as intended), but it disappears after I close the MikTeX Console.
In other words, it doesn't store the change in the directory list.

My texmf directory worked in previous MikTeX version, and has the following structure: ../tex/latex/$packagename$

I tried the same with the old GUI, but the result is the same.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your miktex up-to-date? Did you run the update manager? Did you try to register the root in the miktex command line with `initexmf --register-root=path-to-texmf`?

Comment: Yes, I did run the update manager and everything is up to date. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work (directory doesn't show up in miktex configuration, and the custom texmf is not used when compiling a file).

Comment: Then make a bug report in the miktex issue tracker. (I can't test your issue, I don't have a portable installation).

Comment: Since you are wisely using the portable version: From time to time, when everything is working well, make a zip archive of the entire installation. In the event of update problem, discard the bad installation, and revert to the un-zipped good one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ulrike, I've got the answer after posting a bug report.

@RobtAll you're right, I'll definitely make a backup of the working installation. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got [a response](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/66#issuecomment-365441058) after posting in the issue tracker (it's a bug) and a workaround as well:

```
cd \PATH\TO\MIKTEXPORTABLE
copy texmfs\config\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini texmfs\install\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini
```

This fixes the bug in the current MikTeX Portable version.

Comment: Using Version 2.9.6942, my MikTex broke over last night. Same symptom, tried this method. For one, there is no such `miktexstartup.ini` file anymore. I tried copying the only two files existing, `console.ini` and `miktex.ini`, and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Using portable MiKTeX Console 2.9.7015 (MiKTeX: 2.9.7000). Same symptom, custom TEXMF root directory doesn't survive a console restart.

1. Using the [old workaround](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/66) doesn't help, exactly same symptom.
2. Running the following commands doesn't help, exactly the same symptom.

   initexmf --user-roots="path\to\library"
   initexmf --update-fndb

I solved the problem by manually editing this file in the miktex-portable folder: `texmfs\install\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini`

which only contains a `[Auto]` field. 
I manually add a `[Path]` field containing the following line

```
UserData=path\to\library
```

There are white spaces in my library path, and I did not do anything about it like any quotation mark. 
I do not put any white space around the equal sign.

I reboot console and my tex editor (TeXstudio) and it works again.